# Why does the scroll event for iOS not work for making an element visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I was was experimenting with the scroll event and decided to try to make it fade in a div after the scrollTop() is more than 50. This is my code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {    
        $('#div').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } 
}
```

I also tried this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {    
            $('#div').css('display', 'initial');
        } 
}
```

These both work fine on a computer, but on my phone the div only appears after I let go of the screen. I thought that this applied to all javascript functions on iOS, but I tested it by trying this(the div was visible from the start in this example):

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {

            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {    
                $('#div').css('background-color', 'red');
            } 
            else{
                $('#div').css('background-color', 'green');

               }
    }
```

Surprisingly, everything worked fine. I could scroll up and down, not letting go of the screen of my iPhone, and the colour would change. What is the cause of this? Why can some actions be done, while others not? I do not understand why the fading in of an element does not follow the examples shown [here.](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/)

Answer (score 0):

iOS pauses the javacript on scroll. With there browser you can only do things before and after scroll events.

I want to support my answer with this link.
[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_scroll.asp)

Here is an alternative solution.

[Iscroll Probe](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/probe/)

UPDATE

SCRIPT

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {


$(window).scroll(function (event) {



    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = scroll;


}); 

        });
```

HTML

```
 <div style="z-index: 1000; position:fixed;width:100px;height:100px;color:red;top:100px;left:100px; " class="output" id="output"></div>
```

This worked fine on my iPhone 6. The script was updating on scroll. So I believe the answer to your problem is adding the `$( document ).ready(function() { });` to the function you already have.